# How do you mock/stub backtick system calls in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method that uses backticks but the stub is not working for it. It is pulling the result of ls:

```
class TestHelper
  def self.test_method
    `ls`
  end
end
```

rspec test:

```
describe TestHelper do
  describe '.test_method' do
    subject { described_class.test_method }
    before { Kernel.stub(:`).and_return("test_dir") }
    it { expect(subject).to eql("test_dir") } 
  end
end
```

Comment: must you stub the system call? why not just stub the method?

Comment: what method? the ` method? how do you do that?

Comment: test_method is the method i'm <b>testing</b>. why would I stub that out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to test here. That backticks  work? That you're calling ls? If you weren't, wouldn't things fail elsewhere?

Answer (score 13):

`TestHelper` receives it, and then delegates that to `Kernel`. So, stub `TestHelper`:

```
describe TestHelper do
  describe '.test_method' do
    subject { described_class.test_method }
    before { allow(described_class).to receive(:`).and_return("test_dir") }
    it { is_expected.to eql("test_dir") } 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `ls` in a method, and stub that method out.

```
def ls
  `ls`
end
```

Stub this method to return whatever you'd like. You don't need to test the system call.

Comment: this is a workaround - see @ramon-tayag's answer - it's spot on.

Comment: It's highly recommended not to stub your class under test. See [Why not stub the System Under Test](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/don-t-stub-the-system-under-test) for more info

Answer (score 3):

Since your `TestHelper` class inherits from `Object`, it has a backtick method as well because ["[t]he Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are available in every Ruby object."](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html).

If you want to test that `TestHelper.test_method` calls the [Kernel#`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60) method with `'ls'` as an argument, rather than what it actually returns (I'm assuming this because that's all your method does: it doesn't use the value returned from `ls` in any other operation. If it did, stubbing out that value to use in the other operations would make sense) you can do away with testing the value of a stubbed out method and just test that the expected backtick method is called on your own `TestHelper` class.  However, in case you still want to use stubbed method calls, I've put both ways of potentially testing this below:

```
describe TestHelper do
  describe '.test_method' do
    describe 'called methods' do
      it 'calls the `ls` command' do
        expect(described_class).to receive(:`).with('ls')
        described_class.test_method
      end
    end

    describe 'result' do
      let(:test_method) { described_class.test_method }
      let(:directories) { 'test_dir' }

      before do
        allow(described_class).to receive(:`).with('ls').and_return(directories)
      end

      it 'equals the expected directories' do
        expect(test_method).to eq(directories)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stub any instance of Module:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Module).to receive(:`).and_return("test_dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `stub` doesn't work for the backtick method. (I'd have to look at the RSpec source, and I don't have time right now.) But you can stub it out yourself, manually:

```
module Kernel
  def `(*args); "test_dir"; end
end
```